# How to use point cursor over ion-icon with button (Ionic 4)

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

I have an ionic clickable icon (svg) and I placed it in a button. I set the fill to clear because I only want that the point cursor appears. The icon is in a grid on a cell.

Without the button around it looks correctly like this

[image]

With the button around it looks like that

[image]

The row is defined in this way. I set no-padding because in the next row I have  more icons and the padding should be minimal.

```
      <ion-row no-padding>
      <ion-col></ion-col>
      <ion-col ion-item no-lines no-padding text-center (click)="cmbAButton.open()">
          <ion-button icon-only fill="clear" >
            <ion-icon class="big" src="/assets/{{aSelectedIcon}}.svg"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

In scss I have

```
 ion-icon {
  &.big {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
```

Comment: post your code and check the height and width of the button

Comment: Just a thought... ionic projects would be for mobile, there's no cursors there, if that is the reason for this attempt.

Comment: Not only, you can use electron like I do.

Comment: @AJT82 That's not really true. You can use it to compile to web apps, too.